# How do I move data across Fragments and Activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating an android app that is supposed to have a viewPager and a search fragment. The viewpager is using two fragments and I am using a thrid fragment in the search button.

All these are interconnected through the MainActivity.java

I want to the functionality to be such that when the user selects or enters any input into the search fragment, this fragment will work upon the data and then send it to main activity.

Suppose the user searches for the movie avengers, they enter in the search button "The Avengers", now I will be using API, so the search fragment will convert this into 'the+avengers' and then send it to main activity.

The main activity will then send it to one of the fragments within the viewPager, the fragment will then combine the input along with the main base query, search on the servers, and then display the output.

Can someone please help me move the data, in string/integer/etc formats from the search fragment to the main activity and then to the viewPagers!!

The source code for the viewPager:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(tabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface for communication and implement it in your activity. Then in the onAttach of the desired fragment, you get the reference to the interface implementation and you can call it every time you want.

Since you are implementing the interface in the activity, you have the reference for all fragments.

In your case, in can define an interface called Searchable with a method called Search. You can implement this interface in the Activity and in the fragment`s search you call it.

You can get a detailed implementation and examples [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)